# sfGuard and propel pager

Tags: symfony1, propel, pager, sfguard

I would like to be able to user sfPropelPager with sfGuard's user table.

I can do the following just fine:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(sfGuardUserPeer::CREATED_AT);
$this->users = sfGuardUserPeer::doSelect($c);
```

But I cannot do:

```
$pager = new sfPropelPager('sf_guard_user', 20);
$pager->setPage($this->getRequestParameter('page', 1));

$c = new Criteria();
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(sfGuardUserPeer::CREATED_AT);

$pager->setCriteria($c);
$pager->setPeerMethod('doSelect');
$pager->init();
$this->users = $pager;
```

Am I doing something painfully stupid here?

Comment: There isn't really an error message, it's a conceptual problem.

Obviously, i do get: Class 'sf_guard_user' not found in /usr/local/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/addon/sfPropelPager.class.php on line 167 

but that is because, obviously, sfPropel hasn't got models created for sfGuard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used propel for a while, but as I remember, you should put the class name in the constructor, not the table name - so instead of `sf_guard_user` try it with `sfGuardUser`. The class itself is in `plugins/sfGuardPlugin/lib/model`.

Comment: Wow, I just knew I was doing something stupid. I have the excuse of being new to Symfony in general, so thank you for your help! :D